# Android WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am developing game in android using cocos2d-x plateform. I include game .so file in android code. Game working fine in marshmallow and below version devices but when i run this app in android 7 nougat getting unknown error.

```
E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libstlport.so" not found
```

I am sure that problem is in .so file. in .so file following line creating problem. sounds not working in android 7 Nougat.

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->playEffect(writable);
```

is it any alternate method to play sound in cocos2d-x plateform.

Comment: file format of your audio file ? Device model with manufacturing company ?

Comment: Have you tried `experimental::AudioEngine` ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan audio format .mp3 device model MI note 2 rooted

Comment: from cocos2d-x [wiki](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Audio#Sound-Effects), `.mp3` not supported on Android for sound effect, Am i right or wiki is outdated ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan yes you are right i convert sound files into .m4a then its working fine in android 7 nougat. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Sound Effects, `.mp3` only supports on iOS, According to cocos2d-x [wiki](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Audio#Sound-Effects) :

**Sound Effects**

```
|    Platform     |   supported sound effects formats   |
|-----------------|:-----------------------------------:|
| Android Supports|         .ogg , .wav format.         |
| iOS             |          .mp3, .wav, .caf           |   
| Windows Desktop |         .mid and .wav only          |
```

May be wiki is outdated so some OS of Android start supporting `.mp3` file for Sound Effect.  But from your test still android 7 nougat version not supporting `.mp3` file.